# How to add Google TPU to javascript coded web application at AWS?

Tags: web, google, application, javascript

*Edit; I think I just realized that what they are selling is not an add on item to your existing web application, but that they want you to use their servers(instead of AWS), and are implying that server errors to lower end devices(from javascript web applications) will cease or at least improve, if you switch to their service?*
  Sorry, their language was obfuscatory-I thought this was software that could be added externally to a Javascript type web application to jack up its ability to serve low end devices... 
To extend the realm of answers here-is there such a beast?
Or also, is this a justifiable reason to move my javascript code web app from aws amazon web services to google cloud for business?

I just read that Google's new TPU system can help me to serve my Javascript web application, better, to clients with lower end devices, who have been getting error messages when using the web tool...

I am not a developer, I am an inventor, who hired a developer to automate my manual steps, to make it easier for people to do the function for themselves...

We chose Javascript because I could serve the tool cheaply, which meant it could help a wider audience and be sustainable long term...

But I have found that many people who need to use the service, have older or lower quality devices and/or internet connections(rural), and they are getting error messages instead of help...

I have been trying to find ways to jack up the service on my end, to prevent error messages from occurring on their end...

When I read that Google's new TPU system does this, I got interested, but much of the documentation is too cryptic for me to understand...

Is there anyone here who understands this new TPU system, who could explain to me in English, how I could add this to my site?

I am not clear as to which specific service within this category to ask for, how you install it, and can any developer do this for me in my AWS code repository, or does this need the original developer to add code to the original files?

I apologize if this question is too beginner for this forum, but I figure it doesn't hurt to ask?

the site can be found by going to nidi.help if anyone wants to look at it there...